# Android XML parsing stopped at first child

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

I'm trying to parse an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cartoonia xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <stagione nome="Cartoonia Speciale due per vedere se funziona">
        <puntata>
            <numero>0</numero>
            <titolo>Ciao Cipo</titolo>
            <link>http://www.dimaleinpentium.com/app/download/5429764359/Cartoonia+%288%5E+Puntata%29.mp3?t=1389213968</link>
            <descrizione>Ma ciao mia bella Cipo</descrizione>
        </puntata>
    </stagione> 
    <stagione nome="Stagione 1">
        <puntata>
            <numero>1</numero>
            <titolo>Puntata 1</titolo>
            <link>http://www.dimaleinpentium.com/app/download/5424302459/Cartoonia+1%5E+Puntata.mp3?t=1383736417</link>
            <descrizione>Descrizione</descrizione>
        </puntata>
        <puntata>
            <numero>2</numero>
            <titolo>Puntata 2</titolo>
            <link>http://www.dimaleinpentium.com/app/download/5425828359/Cartoonia+%282%5E+Puntata%29.mp3?t=1384351442</link>
            <descrizione>Descrizione</descrizione>
        </puntata>
        <puntata>
            <numero>3</numero>
            <titolo>Puntata 3</titolo>
            <link>http://www.dimaleinpentium.com/app/download/5427087659/Cartoonia+%283%5E+Puntata%29.mp3?t=1384981673</link>
            <descrizione>Descrizione Puntata</descrizione>
        </puntata>
    </stagione>
    <stagione nome="Cartoonia Special!">
        <puntata>
            <numero>0</numero>
            <titolo>Ciao Cipo</titolo>
            <link>http://www.dimaleinpentium.com/app/download/5429764359/Cartoonia+%288%5E+Puntata%29.mp3?t=1389213968</link>
            <descrizione>Ma ciao mia bella Cipo</descrizione>
        </puntata>
    </stagione> 
</cartoonia>
```

With this code (taken from AndroidDevs and modified to fit my file) I can read only first `<stagione>`, the others are ignored.

```
public Map < String, List < Entry >> parse(InputStream in ) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput( in , null);
        parser.nextTag();
        return readFeed(parser);
    } finally { in .close();
    }
}


private Map < String, List < Entry >> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    Map < String, List < Entry >> entries = new HashMap < String, List < Entry >> ();
    String index = "";
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "cartoonia");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "> " + parser.getLineNumber() + " <");
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        Log.d(TAG, "" + name);

        if (name.equals("stagione")) {
            index = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "nome");
            Log.d(TAG, "    " + index);
            entries.put(index, new ArrayList < Entry > ());
        } else if (name.equals("puntata")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "        Entry: " + parser.getName());
            List < Entry > en = entries.get(index);
            en.add(readEntry(parser));
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return entries;
}

// Parses the contents of an entry. If it encounters a title, summary, or link tag, hands them off
// to their respective "read" methods for processing. Otherwise, skips the tag.
private Entry readEntry(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "puntata");
    String title = null;
    String summary = null;
    String link = null;
    String number = null;

    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("titolo")) {
            title = readTitle(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("numero")) {
            number = readNumber(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("descrizione")) {
            summary = readSummary(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("link")) {
            link = readLink(parser);
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return new Entry(title, number, summary, link);
}
```

No errors or warnings or exceptions are shown. If I change the order of the `<stagione>` I obtain the same results, so I don't think that it's a file's problem.

Comment: Not a big file.  Please try to step through with the debugger.

Comment: It seems a logical problem, not a syntax error...is debug usefull in this case?

Comment: You bet debugging will help.  This is a small file you'd be done in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, i can't understand here, it's looking like you're thinking "stagione" and "puntata" are neighbour tags, but they are not neighbour, "puntata" is element of "stagione", so, you need to create another parser inside each "stagione" to read "puntata"'s

```
if (name.equals("stagione")) {
            index = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "nome");
            Log.d(TAG, "    " + index);
            entries.put(index, new ArrayList < Entry > ());
        } else if (name.equals("puntata")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "        Entry: " + parser.getName());
            List < Entry > en = entries.get(index);
            en.add(readEntry(parser));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your loop condition:

```
while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) { ...
```

You're mixing up `END_TAG` with `END_DOCUMENT`. I'm adding you an example that could fit to your implementation. I added as many comments as I could. Take a look at this:

```
int eventType;

while ((eventType = parser.getEventType()) != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
  String current_tag = null;
  switch (eventType) {
    case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
      // Do the pertinent initializations here (if you need, if not, just break)
      break;

    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
      current_tag = parser.getName();               // Get current tag
      if (current_tag.equals("cartoonia")
        continue;
      else if (current_tag.equals("stagione"))      // Initialize a new object to store a "stagione", probably add the name from "nome"
        myStagione = new WhatEver(); 
      else if (current_tag.equals("puntata"))       // Do the proper initialization to store a "puntata"
        myPuntata = new WhatEver2(); 
      else if (myPuntata != null) {                 // Just do the same!
        ...
      }

      break;

    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:                     // This is called if you terminated processing a tag, not at the end of the XML file!
      current_tag = parser.getName();
      ...

      break;
    }

  eventType = parser.next();                        // Next event
}
```

Comment: My `START_TAG` is "cartoonia" so I thought that `END_TAG` is "cartoonia" again. Am I wrong? In an earlier step my XML was without any "stagione", it was only `<cartoonia><puntata>...</puntata><puntata>...</puntata><puntata>...</puntata></cartoonia>` and all "puntata" tags was processed.

Comment: I think you indeed are wrong, way you're having several `START_TAG` tag and you'll have to distinguish between them (with `if` sentences). `END_TAG` will match `</puntata>` and `</stagione>`, so it's the analogue process, you'll need to distinguish between them and process that data correctly, but the main thing is that your loop condition was `END_TAG`, so your loop was exiting on the first of them and that's not what you want, simply iterate over `END_DOCUMENT` instead.

Comment: I'm not telling you are wrong but why all "puntata" inside a "stagione" are processed while only the first "stagione" is? I mean, if `END_TAG` will match both `</puntata>` and `</stagione>` then it should stop at the first `</puntata>`...I need to understand this situation, so thanks for the help :)

Comment: I think this is because when one of you conditions match, you're passing `parser` to your functions, instead of `parser.nextText()` which should return the next item you just processed. I can't see the content of those functions, but are you getting the items via `parser.nextText()`?

Comment: By the way, you won't have just 2 `START_TAG` and `END_TAG`, but 3, as your `cartoonia` tag also counts. The `START_DOCUMENT` simply says you're at the beggining of the document, but nothing has been read yet, so you'll have to process the third one too. More info here http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#START_DOCUMENT

Comment: The functions `readSomething` are structured only for read the text inside a tag, so they are something like `parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "something"); String text = parser.getText();` (at the moment I can't access to the entire code, I have it on another PC).

Comment: I would use `Log.d()` within your loop to see why is it acting this way, probably there's some little detail you're missing right now - but this way it should work. I'm using this on 2 projects with one less depth-level than you, but it should be the same (a bit more messing though, since you have to bare with more tags).

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try it this evening and then I'll tell you results. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I upvote your answer to thanks you but this doesn't work well as I want. I have to accept Alobar Non's answer, it seems better. Thank you anyway :)